# Multiple sql in PHP code and error message

Tags: php, mysql, auto-increment

I am having the following php code, which delete a row from my table. I would like to add after deleting to rearrange auto increment. This is temp table(max 20 rows), but user want to see counting correct.

My line that i want to add is the following:

```
ALTER TABLE tblmonitor AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

My code as is, without the above line:

```
if ($action == "deleteChanges") {
    $monitor_id   = $_REQUEST['monitor_id'];
    $sql      = 'DELETE FROM tblmonitor WHERE monitor_id = "' . $monitor_id . '"';
    $sql      = $connection->query($sql);
    $error    = $connection->errorInfo();
    if ($error[1] == null) {
        $result = array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => 'Record has been deleted successfully.'
        );
        echo json_encode($result);
    } else {
        $result = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => $error[2]
        );
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
```

I was thinking to add it after `DELETE SQL` and the new code will look like this:

```
    $sql      = 'DELETE FROM tblmonitor WHERE monitor_id = "' . $monitor_id . '"';
    $sql      = 'ALTER TABLE tblmonitor AUTO_INCREMENT = 1';
    $sql      = $connection->query($sql);
    $error    = $connection->errorInfo();
```

Is not the correct way, but how can i fix it and make it work fine with the error?

Comment: This is a recipe for a world of hurt. There is absolutely no need to fiddle with `autoincrement` after every deletion. It will just cause trouble.

Comment: What error do you get? I'm not sure that you can set the auto_increment to a lower value than you already have used in your table.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? why do you need this ?

Comment: @MaxMuster User want to see auto increment correct!!! It is a small teml tabler.

Comment: @Gowire Table will be empty or with 1-20 rows. Every time, user delete one, he wants to see correct auto increment.

Comment: You can just have another column to contain your neatly-consecutive numbers. The auto-increment field is purely an ID. It should **uniquely** identify that row **forever**. It should have no other meaning or purpose beyond that. If you change it, then other code or applications which might have links to the data would break. As the first comment says, it's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @ADyson I know that, it is a temp table and the ids are not used anywhere in the app. My best solution is to add another action with the alter table.

Comment: `it is a temp table` ...then what is the point of worrying what ID numbers exist. That doesn't make much sense to me. But anyway it's still simpler to add a second "numbering" column that it is to mess about with the auto_increment field - it's just not designed to be interfered with. Or if you're using mysql 8, you can probably use a CTE query to auto-generate consecutive row numbers for you on-demand.

Comment: you must write a small function for this that iterates every row and rewrites the id. As far as I know there is no such function in MySQL that can rewrite the indexes as you want. More exact first you determine the index of the row you want to delete and the max index , then you delete it, and then you make a for loop with a UPDATE where you replace the id (between the id of the deleted row, and the max id) by one unit smaller.

Comment: Why is your user even looking at the tables? If your user has anything more that `SELECT` access and he's making requests like this now, then one day he'll 'tidy up' something and your carefully constructed schema will come crashing down.